# PLSQL Call Procedure If Exists Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, exists

**I'm using Oracle 9i.**

*Cue pseudo-code!*

I have Stored Procedure A:

```
PROCEDURE stored_proc_a
IS
BEGIN
    insert into...
END;
```

Then, I have Stored Procedure B:

```
PROCEDURE stored_proc_b
IS
BEGIN
    stored_proc_a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM...);
END;
```

As you can see from my pseudo-code, I would like to *call* procedure A *from* procedure B, if a given row *does not* exist in a table.

I can't find any documentation that would suggest that the WHERE EXISTS clause can be used with a procedure call (the examples show its use with INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE).

Can I use WHERE EXISTS with a procedure call, and if not, what would be the correct code to do a procedure call based on the absence of a particular record in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is the following:

```
PROCEDURE stored_proc_b
    IS
        num_rows number;
    BEGIN
        select COUNT(*)  into num_rows
            FROM my_table
            WHERE my_table.xyz = 123; -- (whatever is appropriate)

        if num_rows < 1
        then
            stored_proc_a;
        end if;
    END;
```

Figured this out thanks to [Nicholas Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217912/700471) and [WBAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786354/700471) for their info on other posts.

Comment: Minor nitpick; I'd add an additional condition WHERE ROWNUM < 2 to your SELECT statement as you only need to determine existence you only need to look for 1 row.

Comment: It works, but I've found a better solution (in my opinion at least) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217600/if-exists-condition-not-working-with-plsql

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving the same, in case you you want to call it for multiple rows and want to use data from Table in procedure B-

```
PROCEDURE stored_proc_b
IS
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT COL1 FROM <<TABLE1>> T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM <<TABLE2>> T2...WHERE T1.JOIN_COL = T2.JOIN_COL))
    LOOP
        stored_proc_a;
    END LOOP;    
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    rollback;
END;
```