# How to write procedure delete 3 months old records from table and send old count and new count over mail

Tags: oracle11g

I have written below procedure to delete records from table and record old and new rowcount in another table.

```
create or replace procedure delete_old_records_job  as
DECLARE
COUNTER PLS_INTEGER:=1;
drop table SIEBEL.RETAILORDER_DETAILS_COUNT;
CREATE TABLE SIEBEL.RETAILORDER_DETAILS_COUNT (TABLE_COUNT_OLD varchar(64) NOT NULL,TABLE_COUNT_NEW varchar(64) NOT NULL);
 insert into  SIEBEL.RETAILORDER_DETAILS_COUNT( TABLE_COUNT_OLD )SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIEBEL.Z_VIEWS_BACKUP;
BEGIN
WHILE COUNTER>0 LOOP
   DELETE FROM SIEBEL.Z_VIEWS_BACKUP WHERE LAST_UPD < add_months(sysdate, -3) AND ROWNUM<25000;
   COUNTER:=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   COMMIT;
END LOOP

insert into  SIEBEL.RETAILORDER_DETAILS_COUNT( TABLE_COUNT_NEW ) 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIEBEL.Z_VIEWS_BACKUP;
END;
```

I am getting below error while executing

```
SQL> show errors procedure delete_old_records_job;
Errors for PROCEDURE DELETE_OLD_RECORDS_JOB:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of
         the following:
         begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
         exists prior external language
         The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

4/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting one of
         the following:
         begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
         exists prior
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error when declaring variables in a pl/sql procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786312/syntax-error-when-declaring-variables-in-a-pl-sql-procedure)

Comment: Still I am getting an error

Comment: SQL> show errors procedure delete_old_records_job;
Errors for PROCEDURE DELETE_OLD_RECORDS_JOB:
6/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/55     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "LAST_UPD": invalid identifier

Comment: SQL> create or replace procedure delete_old_records_job  as
  2  --DECLARE
  3  COUNTER PLS_INTEGER:=1;
  4  Begin
  5   WHILE COUNTER>0 LOOP
  6     DELETE FROM SIEBEL.UNLOCK_TRANSACTION_backup WHERE LAST_UPD < add_months(sysdate, -3) AND ROWNUM<25000;
  7     COUNTER:=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  8     COMMIT;
  9  END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /

Kindly suggest, still procedure is not running properly