# In Oracle procedure, how to define local variable and use it after DECLARE block?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a stored proc like below

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AAA
(
  cv_1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
as
BEGIN

  DECLARE ord_t VARCHAR2(20);
  begin
  SELECT order_type into ord_t from BT;
  dbms_output.Put_line(ord_t);
  end;

  if ord_t = 'xxx' THEN
      open cv_1 for
      select * from BA;
  else
      open cv_1 for
      select * from BB;
  END if;

END;
```

But there is error saying ord_t must be declared. How do I write this correctly? The purpose of the proc is to return results from either BA or BB based on the value of ord_t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variable before the BEGIN-tag in which it should be used

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AAA(cv_1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
  ord_t VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT order_type into ord_t from BT;
  dbms_output.Put_line(ord_t);

  if ord_t = 'xxx' THEN
      open cv_1 for
      select * from BA;
  else
      open cv_1 for
      select * from BB;
  END if;

END;
```

In procedures, the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE name(params) AS` replaces the `DECLARE` of a block. Therefor, you don't need it here.

The definition of a block is

```
DECLARE or CREATE FUNCTION/PROCEDURE
  (variables in block)
BEGIN
  (code using variables)
END
```

Examples:

```
declare
  myvar number(1);
begin
  --begin scope of myvar--
  select 1 into myvar from dual;
  --end scope of myvar--
end;

create procedure myproc (var1 in number)
as
  myvarouter number(1);
begin
  --begin scope myvarouter--
  declare
    myvarinner number(1);
  begin
    --begin scope myvarinner--
    select 1 into myvarinner from dual;
    select 1 into myvarouter from dual;
    --end scope myvarinner--
  end;
  select 1 into myvarouter from dual;
  --end scope myvarouter--
end;
```

Another question with the same content can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786312/syntax-error-when-declaring-variables-in-a-pl-sql-procedure)

Comment: what is your sql developer version? Mine is 4.2 and I get compile error:
Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

Comment: @Sheen excuse me, my bad. I made a copy-paste error. I also added a explanation that the header `create procedure/function` replaces the declare statement